# How to present features of aggregate functions (NULL)?

Tags: sql, database, aggregate-functions

I'm looking for 'textbook' example of database to illustrate salient features of the aggregate functions (Max, Min, Sum, Avg and Count) when NULL values are involved.

I must be able to discuss and illustrate/present the usage of these aggregates function in the presence of NULLs with example queries and their answers, using mentioned database.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT MAX(t.num) AS max_test, 
       MIN(t.num) AS min_test,
       SUM(t.num) AS sum_test,
       AVG(t.num) AS avg_test,
       COUNT(t.num) AS count_test,
       COUNT(*) AS count_star_test
  FROM (SELECT NULL AS num
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3) t
```

Output should be:

```
max_test | min_test | sum_test | avg_test | count_test | count_star_test
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
3        | 1        | 6        | 2        | 3          | 4
```

In summary, NULL is ignored by aggregate functions if you reference the column specifically.  `COUNT` is the only aggregate function that supports `*` - `COUNT(*)` will include NULLs in this case.

Comment: I will point out that null is not ignored when you use count(*) instead of count(Fieldname)

Answer (score 0):

Null values are the value which is unknown.
All aggregate functions except the count function ignores the null value.

I have taken example form database system concepts by korth.Here is an instructor relation

```
ID        name        dept        salary
22222     Einstein    Physics     95000 
12121     Wu          Finance     90000
32343     El Said     History     60000 
45565     Katz        Comp. Sci.  75000 
98345     Kim Elec.   Eng.        80000 
12131     jake        music       null
```

I have ignored few tuples and inserted a new tuple (12131,jake,music,null) to illustrate aggregate function on null values.

```
select sum(salary) from instructor;
result 400000
select min(salary) from instructor;
result 60000
select count(*) from instructor;
result 6
```

Similar result holds for max and avg function.Only the count function takes in account of null values.